# Real use of same origin policy

Tags: same-origin-policy

I just got to know about the same origin policy in WebAPI. Enabling CORS helps to call a web service which is present in different domain.

My understanding is NOT enabling CORS will only ensure that the webservice cannot be called from browser. But if I cannot call it from browser I still can call it using different ways e.g. fiddler.

So I was wondering what's the use of this functionality. Can you please throw some light? Apologies if its a trivial or a stupid question.

Thanks and Regards,
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all a stupid question, it's a very important aspect when you're dealing with web services with different origin.

To get an idea of what CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is, we have to start with the so called Same-Origin Policy which is a **security concept for the web**. Sounds sophisticated, but only makes sure a web browser permits scripts, contained in a web page to access data on another web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin. In other words, requests for data must come from the same scheme, hostname, and port. If http://player.example tries to request data from http://content.example, the request will usually fail.

After taking a second look it becomes clear that this prevents the unauthorized leakage of data to a third-party server. Without this policy, a script could read, use and forward data hosted on any web page. Such cross-domain activity might be used to exploit cookies and authentication data. Therefore, this security mechanism is definitely needed.

If you want to store content on a different origin than the one the player requests, there is a solution – CORS. In the context of XMLHttpRequests, it defines a set of headers that allow the browser and server to communicate which requests are permitted/prohibited. It is a recommended standard of the W3C. In practice, for a CORS request, the server only needs to add the following header to its response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

For more information on settings (e.g. GET/POST, custom headers, authentication, etc.) and examples, refer to http://enable-cors.org.

For a detail read, use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response and the detailed explanation.